# Maven, isnt faster to download the .jars yourself?

Tags: java, maven

I understand the benefits of Maven, but if i have to configure pom.xml, then isn't it more difficult than the alternatives? As an example, consider the following pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mastertheboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hibernate4Example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

How can I know that the artifact ID is mysql-connecto-java, and what is the version supposed to be? I have to look in the website of the MySQL JDBC driver to find this, for example. Now I need the postgresql, and I have to search on Google for "Pom.xml for postgresql". If i go to the postgresql websote, I can download the jdbc_driver.jar directly.  That's faster isn't it?

How should I find this information (artifact IDs and versions) without a Google search?

Comment: What's your question? Maven (or really, the dependency resolution portion that you're talking about) helps you automate a project's build. It's faster initially to just go seek out the jars yourself from Maven Central, but what if you had to do this 5 times, or 100 times for the same project? What if you are working on the same project with a team of 20 people? Probably easier to have the project `pom.xml` in that case.

Comment: See http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html : *"Maven, a Yiddish word meaning accumulator of knowledge,..."* - That's exactly what it is. All you need to know is accumulated in the POM, and it works for everyone, out-of-the-box. (In the best case ;-)). The dependency info is usually stated prominently on any site that offers a mavenized library

Comment: Some IDEs will help you in finding artifact IDs, too.  E.g., in Eclipse you can start by typing `mysql`, and you'll get a list of artifacts that you can include.  It takes some familiarity before you'll be absolutely confident in your choices, but then again, it's easy to undo a change by reverting your pom.xml to an earlier version (you're using version control, of course).

Comment: And also consider transitive dependencies which get downlaoded automatically without explicitly listing them in the POM.

Comment: "I understand the benefits of Maven" from the question you are asking, and comment you made in other answer, obviously you don't understand the benefits of Maven.

Comment: @AdrianShum i was expecting in maven something like this: i add in the  pom the hibernate dependency, and the maven auto download all the needed .jars, but now i know that i have to specify each .jar there.

Comment: The power in Maven for dependency management for me stems from two different occurrences: when I want to update to a new version; that is a 2 second action with Maven, just change the pom and DONE. And when I start a new project, which is incredibly basic when you can simply adapt the Maven poms from an existing application. All of a sudden setting up a project complete with dependencies is like 5 minutes of work. Of course sharing your project with others is also a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i know this "artifactID" and "Version" without looking in the
>   google?

I dont know what's the problem looking in google, but if you prefer and use Eclipse, just click on right button in pom.xml, Maven, Add dependency and type the name of dependency you want.

I prefer search in the google like  `"postgre maven dependency"`, in general will see http://mvnrepository.com/ direct link to your dependency in maven central repository, the most jar projects you can found in Maven Central, but you can also add others repository in the pom.xml

PostgreSQL dependency (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901.jdbc4)

```
<dependency>
<groupId>postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

you can add others repository in your pom.xml like this

```
    <repository>
        <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
        <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
    </repository>
```

Version dependency

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.27</mysql.version>
</properties>
```

Using dependency with version defined above

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


   <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Using properties, you can change dependency version in just one place

Maven is very usefull management dependency, and more, you can add build features to your project.

Comment: i got what you mean! but for example, if i need to add Hibernate.. you have to look in Maven Repository, about the: 1) Hibernate Core, 2) javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, 3) hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar... and other .jars.. but you have to download the zip containing all the .jars so you will know the number and the name of each .jar!! i was expecting something like just add hibernate  and it will find all the needed jars for me.. im wrong ?

Comment: @user2582318 You're wrong. Maven 2.x supports transitive dependencies, so if, for example, Hibernate needed 5 other dependencies, those will be brought in.

Comment: Indeed. If you want to use JPA, you'd only need to add hibernate-entitymanager and then you get the correct matching version of hibernate-core for free without any effort at all. God I love Maven (and the people who properly setup their poms). Besides that, red hat tends to setup a BOM too which provides you ALL dependencies at once.

Comment: @birryree so if i add in the pom just this: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
 <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: it will bring me all the others .jars, i dont need to manually add the other dependencies???

Comment: @Gimby hummmm look my above comment please

Comment: @user2582318 [Look at the Hibernate 4.3.0-final dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.0.Final). Those are the things that will be brought in when you use Maven to do dependency resolution (`antlr`, `dom4j`, `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`, `javassist`, etc.).

Comment: @birryree i got, the last question, so if i see in the that link you provided the dependency resolution, i have to add each one in the pom.xml or the maven do this for me?

Comment: @user2582318 You only need to add `hibernate-core` to your `pom.xml` to get the other things it depends on.

Comment: @birryree i got, thanks i will do some test, thank you so much ;*!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply search on the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org).

Comment: I would prefer Maven Central.

Comment: i go what you mean, but, i look for hibernate i have to take the info, but the hibernate need the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, so i have to look for this one, but need the javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, but need other jars... and go on... if it change the version i have to look the new version for every point in the pom.xml and change,

isnt it fast to just download the zip?!

just asking, i got what you mean but i think im doing something wrong, maven is not making "automated" or "easy" dependency control

Comment: @user2582318 dependencies are transitive, so you would only to declare the first jar. Also IDE support: in NetBeans placing the the cursor in `<version>` and doing `Ctrl+Space` will shown versions numbers available.

Comment: Google "maven <dependency name>" works equally well for me. Usually you get a direct link to the mvnrepository entry for the dependency, and if its not in maven central I tend to get a link to the third party maven repository / nexus.